# Need help with understanding of the interchange between chain rule and linear transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I come across this theorem in a Advanced Calculus text.  It concerns the chain rule of n variables.  The theorem states:

Let $L$$\in $Lin$(\mathbb R^{p}, \mathbb R^{q}.$ Then $\ D \circ L$=$L \circ D,\ $that is, for every mapping $f:U \to \mathbb R^{p}\ $differentiable at $a\in$$U$ we have, if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n},$

$$D(Lf)(a)=L(Df)(a)$$
Proof:  Using the chain rule and the linearity of $L$ we find

$$D(L \circ f)(a)=DL(f(a)) \circ Df(a)=L \circ (Df)(a).$$

What I would like to know is, how did the author got the right hand side equality: in the proof $DL(f(a)) \circ Df(a)=L \circ (Df)(a).$

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential of a linear map at a point is itself, so $DL(f(a))=L$.

Note that $L(c+h)-L(c)-L(h)=0$, and hence $\dfrac{|L(c+h)-L(c)-L(h)|}{|h|}=0\rightarrow 0$, so by uniqueness of differential, $DL(c)=L$.

Comment: @user2843331, thank you for your reply.  I just have one last question, do you mean i should treat $(DL)(a)$, like matrix $Ax$ then, $D(Ax)=DA$ where x is in $\mathbb R^{p}$

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But $(DL)(a)$ is a matrix $A$ in some sense, so $(DL)(a)(x)=Ax$ for $x\in{\bf{R}}^{p}$.

Comment: what I meant is to treat (DL)(f(a)) like $DAx,$ where in $(DL)(f(a)),$ $f(a)$ is a vector just like $x$ is a vector in $Ax$.

Comment: Okay, that goes through.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it.  :)